# WhatsApp on Android 4.4 works only briefly and after rebooting phone

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, whatsapp-messenger

I have a Huawei smartphone running Android 4.4. I am experiencing a strange issue with the device, specifically with WhatsApp: the app will only work (as in sending and receiving messages and calls) for a few hours, then suddenly it is unable to connect to the Internet at all, it does not matter if the phone is connected to local Wi-Fi or to the mobile data network.

When trying to make use of the app, I get a notification saying "Unable to connect to the Internet. Please check that you're connected to the Internet and try again." The phone is, however, connected, and any other app (including a web browser) will work without any problems. As I said, this will happen regardless of the phone being connected to Wi-Fi or to the data network.

The only solution is to reboot the phone or uninstall and reinstall WhatsApp, but again the solution may last for a few hours at worst a couple of days at best, and then it is unable to connect again.

I've checked the phone settings and seemingly there isn't any permission problems or anything that would stop this app in particular to connect.

This problem did not happen originally and only started happening after the phone changed numbers after moving to a new phone company (and changing the SIM card). Could there be any relation? Anyone has had a similar problem and found a workaround?

Thanks